# Read Avro format in kafka by Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, avro

I try this code:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema=avro.schema.parse(open('ff.avsc','rb').read())
reader = DatumReader(schema)

def decode(msg_value):
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    message_bytes.seek(5)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict

...
decode(message.value)
```

where message.value is my message from kafka

And error appears

```
NameError: name 'BinaryDecoder' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error, I see no import for that class, so that explains that...

Based on `seek(5)`, then you seem to be using Schema Registry encoded data... Which means you need to use the correct libraries.

#### Install

`pip install confluent-kafka[avro]`

#### Consume

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python#usage